# Polar plot $r = 1-2\cos(6\theta)$

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

I have a task for school and we need to plot a polar function with MATLAB. The function is $r = 1-2\cos(6\theta)$.

I did this and I'm getting exactly the same as on Wolfram Alpha: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=polar+plot+r%3D1-2\cos(6theta)

I've used for $\theta$ a value between $0$ and $2\pi$. Now the question explitictly says we need to take into account the period and the domain of the function and we can use the logic function $r>0$ for this. But I didn't do this because I just took a value between $0$ and $2\pi$ for $\theta$. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As the function $r$ has period $\frac\pi3$, the curve is invariant by rotations of angle $\frac\pi 3$. Hence you have to draw a petal of the curve for $0\le\theta\le\frac\pi 3$, and deduce the five other petals by successive rotations.

Comment: Good observation. +1 for this!

Answer (score 1):

Matlab code:

```
 clear all 
 close all

 nPoints = 500; % Number of points for the plot 

 theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, nPoints); % Define the theta points

 r = 1 - 2*cos(6*theta); % Evaluate the radius for each theta

 x = r.*cos(theta); % Evaluate x for each theta
 y = r.*sin(theta); % Evaluate y for each theta

 plot(x,y) % Plot it!!!
```

Output: a nice flower!

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I'm a bit confused now by Bernards comment. Isn't this also just values from $0$ to $2\pi$ for $\theta$?

Comment: @ScoobyDuh Bernard is talking about the symmetry of the picture. Read carefully what he wrote.

Comment: I understand that the period of the function is $\pi/3$ but I don't understand how to deduce the five other petals by successive rotations in MATLAB.

Comment: @ScoobyDuh The comment of Bernard is related to the symmetry of the system. The Matlab code that I proposed works even if the user is not aware about this symmetry.